# C# Recursive Calls and Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I am sitting here finding myself writing a recursive call for C# to write a `RegistryKey`.

This is something I could hard code easily enough, but I'd to do it recursively.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Win32;

private const string regKeyPath = @"Software\Apps\jp2code\net\TestApp";

static void Main() {
  string[] split = regKeyPath.Split('\\');
  RegistryKey key = null;
  try {
    keyMaker(Registry.LocalMachine, split);
  } finally {
    if (key != null) {
      key.Close();
    }
  }
  // continue on with Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

So, `keyMaker` is what I want to be my recursive function.

```
private static void keyMaker(RegistryKey key, string[] path) {
  string subKey = null;
  string[] subKeyNames = key.GetSubKeyNames();
  foreach (var item in subKeyNames) {
    if (path[0] == item) {
      subKey = item;
    }
  }
  RegistryKey key2 = null;
  try {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(subKey)) {
      key2 = key.CreateSubKey(subKey);
    } else {
      key2 = key.OpenSubKey(subKey);
    }
    keyMaker(key2, &path[1]); // <= NOTE! Not allowed/defined in C#
  } finally {
    key2.Close();
  }
}
```

So, I can't simply pass the array starting with the next element of the array.

Is there a neat way to do this in C#?

The *Registry* bit has nothing to do with the problem but to add my real world problem to an array task.

Comment: not sure if it's beneficial to you, but there is a class called `ArraySegment` that you could use to pass the remainder of the path array (without allocating new arrays, and allows you to get back to the original)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to be to change your method's signature to include the starting index:

```
void keyMaker(RegistryKey key, string[] path, int startIndex)
```

Apart from that, you can use a [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) or a [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.aspx) instead of an array, and use `LinkedList<T>.RemoveFirst()` or `Queue<T>.Dequeue()` methods to remove their head elements.

But you don't need recursion to solve this at all (unless this is an exercise).

Comment: It is only an exercise in that I did not see a way to do this using `string[] array`. I never thought of `LinkedList<T>` or `Queue<T>`. Good ideas!

Comment: K.I.S.S. - I just added the index value.

Answer (score 1):

Editted in response to LOL.

```
keyMaker(Registry.LocalMachine, ref split, 0);
....
private static void keyMaker(RegistryKey key, ref string[] path, int index) {
if( index > path.length - 1 ) return;
....
if (path[index] == item) {
....
keyMaker(key2, ref path, ++index);
....
```

Comment: LOL - you used the illegal `&path` in your call to `keyMaker`, but I understand what you meant by the index.

Comment: You don't need to use `ref`. A reference is passed regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it recursively is all. Here's how I'd write it, given that a key is simply returned by [`CreateSubKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.createsubkey.aspx) if it exists:

```
private static void keyMaker(RegistryKey key, string[] path) {
    foreach(string subkey in path) {
        key = key.CreateSubKey(subkey);
    }
}
```

If closing them immediately is important (I doubt it):

```
private static void keyMaker(RegistryKey key, string[] path) {
    RegistryKey lastKey = key;

    foreach(string subkey in path) {
        key = key.CreateSubKey(subkey);
        lastKey.Close();
        lastKey = key;
    }

    lastKey.Close();
}
```

Comment: I like this. It might be the way I go, so don't change it. Still, I'm curious how to pass an array, given an array.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'd prefer passing the index like @Groo suggested, another possibility is to use an `IEnumerable<string>` instead of a `string[]` and use LINQ. In the recursive call, you could pass `path.Skip(1)`, which will remove the first element from the list (or, more precisely, return a new `IEnumerable<string>` which starts on the second element).

Comment: LINQ - I always enjoy finding a place to try out some of that!